# GCP Cron Job MongoDB Backup from mlab

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-functions, mlab, mongodump, google-cloud-scheduler

I wanted to set up a way (using GCP) to automatically and frequently download a copy/backup of one MongoDB instance hosted on mlab and use it to restore/populate another MongoDB instance also on mlab. My thought process was as follows:

1. Create a cron job on GCP using Cloud Scheduler. This cron job would trigger a message on a pub/sub topic every week.
2. Next, I would set up a Cloud Function that would listen to this pub/sub topic, so the cloud function would get called every week
3. Finally, in the cloud function (written in Python), I would somehow call `mongodump` on my mlab mongodb instance. I would then call `mongorestore` with the downloaded backup

My problem is that `mongodump` and `mongorestore` are general command-line utilities and not really associated with Python. Locally, I could just install them, however, I don't think I can do that with the cloud function. My questions are thus,

1. Is there a way for me to use `mongodump` or download a backup from a Cloud Function in Python?
2. Is there an easier way to go about this entire process? (i.e. Download a backup from GCP once a week)

Answer (score 0):

The [Cloud Functions runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system) is read-only except for the `tmp` directory which is writeable. This means that can't run or install executables such as `mongodump` or `mongorestore`.

The possibilities I see for you use case would be:

1. Use a Python MongoDB client library to perform the tasks withing a Cloud Funtion. Maybe [`pymongo`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver)?
2. Use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) with a Docker image that contains `mongodump` and `mongorestore` and call this Cloud Run service from a Cloud Function with an HTTP request.